# Make form validation via custom attributes

Tags: javascript, html

please help me to make validation via input tag's custom attribute (in my case: validation). Help me to change my code that it becomes more dynamic and reusable.

```js
 var validation = function validation(){// out of grid - rename js name

        //validate first name - only letters
        var only_letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;// allow only letters

        if(firstName.value.length === 0){
            document.getElementsByClassName("error")[0].innerHTML="First Name is required";
            formIsValid = false;
        }
        else
        if(firstName.value.match(only_letters)){
            document.getElementsByClassName("error")[0].innerHTML="";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementsByClassName("error")[0].innerHTML="Only characters allowed";
            formIsValid = false;
        }

        //validate email

        var email_letters = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

        if(email.value.length === 0){
            document.getElementsByClassName("error")[2].innerHTML="Email is required";
            formIsValid = false;
        }
        else
        if(email.value.match(email_letters)){
            document.getElementsByClassName("error")[2].innerHTML="";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementsByClassName("error")[2].innerHTML="Incorrect email format";
            formIsValid = false;
        }
```

```html
<form id="user_form" method="post">

    <p> <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" validation="isRequired, correctFormat" /></p>
    <span class="error"></span>
<p><input type="text" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email" validation="isRequired, correctFormat" /></p>
<span class="error"></span>
  </form>
```

Comment: please use a client-side validation library instead of rolling your own, eg: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

Well if you look really carefully, you kinda only have one method in it's essence.
Create a method that gets the element, a regex expression, the response container, and that returns a string.

It would look something like this:

```
function validateMePls(var field, var regex, var placeholder){
    var isValid = "";
    /** do all your checks here (length, regex, etc), appending 'isValid', then return it at the end */
};

var isValid = validateMePls(email, email_letters, document.getElementsByClassName("error")[2]);

/** and now you check 'isValid' for something in it, so you know if you have an error or not */
```

That's basically how an optimized version of your code would look.

Sorry for the 'close to Java' code but I haven't been doing any Javascript lately.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize `placeholder` attribute, `required` attribute, `setCustomValidity()` set to `placeholder` at `invalid` event

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input:not([type=submit])");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity(e.target.placeholder)
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="user_form" method="post">

  <label for="first_name">
    <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+$" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Input letters a-z A-Z" required />
  </label>
  <br>

  <label for="email">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Valid Email is required" required />
  </label>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```